# Socket.io sends multiple emits

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I know a lot of similar questions are out there but I have looked through a lot of them but I'm not able to fix my problem.

I have a tic-tac-toe application that i'm trying to build in react, my first time ever using it, so i do not really get the component, child render part, and I think thats my problem but I do not know how to fix this.

I generate this list of live users, users logged in with firebase, and when one of them is clicked I want to send a emit and create a room where they can play tic-tac-toe in a private room. I've managed to fix this BUT for some reason I get emits now and then from the socket.io, like "chat response client" and "char_request" (see code below). Do I somehow work around this problem, i suspect it has do to something with re-render/setState but i feel like i tried everything.

Render function i LiveUsers component:

```
render() {

    if(this.state.play) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Play userid= {Room} turn={this.state.starter} myColor={myColor} opponentColor={opponentColor}/>
        </React.Fragment>

      );
    }else {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Pick a user to play against</h1>
      <img class="imageBlue" src={this.state.imageBlue} alt=""/>
      <img class="imageYellow" src={this.state.imageYellow} alt=""/>
      <img class="imageBlue2" src={this.state.imageBlue} alt=""/>
      <div className="userlistconent">
        <ul className="userlist">
          {this.renderListBody()}
        </ul>
      </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  }
```

My socket listeners in LiveUser:

```
componentDidMount() {

    let t = this;
    this.props.socket.on('live_users_list', function(usernames,userids,highscores) {
      t.state.userlist = usernames;
      t.state.userids = userids;
      t.setState(t.state);
    });

    this.props.socket.once('chat response client', function(username,room,color) {
        console.log("INSIDE CHAT RESPONSE");
        opponentColor = color;
        myColor = t.setColor(color);
        t.state.play = true;
        Room = room;
        t.setState(t.state);
        t.props.socket.emit('connect room',room,myColor);
        sentData = true;

    });

    this.props.socket.once('chat_request', function(room,color){
        console.log("INSIDE CHAT REQUEST!");
        opponentColor = color;
        t.state.play = true;
        Room = room;
        t.setState(t.state);
        donethisbefore =true;
    });

  }
```

The play function in LiveUsers that starts the request

```
playgame(username) {
    console.log("INSIDE PLAY");
    let color = colorlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorlist.length)];
    starter = true;
    myColor = color;
    console.log("MY COLOR:");
    console.log(myColor);
    this.props.socket.emit("chat request server",username,User,myColor);
  }
```